# Bottom part not display in linear layout using scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I have linear layout but bottom part not display if scrolling data is more then screen size.

**Streaching Bottom Part when Using Scrollview inside the linearlayout, when scrolling data more then height of the device height.**

If i have less data then vertical screen size then all button of bottom appears correctly.

```
public class TestGUI extends LinearLayout {
        sv = new ScrollView(context);   
        hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
        this.addView(topLinearHorizonal);
        hsv.addView(tableLayout);
        sv.addView(hsv);
        this.addView(sv);
        this.addView(fullbottomLinearHorizonal);
        }
```

Edited:

```
LinearLayout fullbottomLinearHorizonal= new LinearLayout(context);
        fullbottomLinearHorizonal.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        fullbottomLinearHorizonal.addView(clearLinearHorizonal);
        fullbottomLinearHorizonal.addView(bottomLinearHorizonal);
```

Comment: Is your ScrollView is a parent layout?

Comment: No,  I have linearlayour in parent. Inside linearlayout scrollview set. this.addView(fullbottomlinearhorizonal); is stretch in mycase. above all date in ok. if i have vertically more data then screen it appers.

Comment: fullbottomLinearHorizonal is a LinearLayout?

Comment: yes. I have please check my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show `fullbottomLinearHorizonal` always at the bottom(visible) you can try below while adding views to `TestGUI`:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams svParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1);
this.addView(sv, svParams);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams fullbottomParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
this.addView(fullbottomLinearHorizonal, fullbottomParams);
```

**Edit:** Also default orientation for LinearLayout is horizontal. [See link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) 
You should better set it vertical at `TestGUI`:

```
this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
```

If you want `fullbottomLinearHorizonal` at the end of the scroll content then you must add it inside of the scrollView.